# Instalación del paquete glmmADMB en el software de R

Tags: r

¿cómo puedo instalar el paquete glmmADMB en el software de R? He intentando de todas las formas posibles: desde una dirección de internet, descargando el archivo zip, en diferentes versiones de R y no lo he podido lograr.

Mi sistema operativo es windows 10.
La versión en R que tengo instalada es la 3.0.0.
Descargué el archivo zip desde la página https://r-forge.r-project.org/R/?group_id=847.

Algunas opciones que intenté fueron las siguientes:

```
install.packages("glmmADMB", repos="http://r-forge.r-project.org")

install.packages("glmmADMB", repos="http://r-forge.r-project.org",type="source")

install.packages("glmmADMB", 
repos=c("http://glmmadmb.r-forge.r-project.org/repos",
        getOption("repos")),
type="source")
```

Comment: Puedes editar tu pregunta e indicar tu sistema operativo, versión de R, si estás tras un proxy (aunque si has descargado el zip a mano), cómo lo has intentado instalar,...?

Comment: Muchas gracias. Ya edité la pregunta para ser más específica con el problema

Comment: Seguramente se deba a un problema de compilación en windows ya que indicas de instalar desde 'source' (no tengo W10 para probar). Prueba a elegir el .exe que mejor se ajuste a tu equipo (32 bits, 64 bits, compilador) de los que hay aquí: http://www.admb-project.org/buildbot/glmmadmb/

Comment: ¿Pero qué tipo de error obtienes a la hora de instalar en cada caso?. En los mensajes de error, aparecen las incompatibilidades, falta de librerías, etc...

Answer (score 1):

Prueba con las siguientes líneas de código:

```
install.packages("R2admb")
install.packages("glmmADMB", 
             repos=c("http://glmmadmb.r-forge.r-project.org/repos",
                     getOption("repos")),
             type="source")
```

Si te surgen más dudas en esta página puede que se te resuelvan
http://glmmadmb.r-forge.r-project.org/